# How should ampersands be encoded in xml to be parsed properly by .net?

Tags: .net, xml, encoding

The following minimal test case throws an error in powershell:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('system.xml.linq')
[system.xml.linq.xdocument]::parse('<node>&</node>')
```

and frankly, in any .net library. This is a real problem when storing urls - for examaple if the content of `<node>` was `http://test.com/?one=a&two=b`.

How should it be properly encoded?

Comment: It's defined as "&amp;" in the XML grammar and has nothing to do with .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An encoded ampersand in XML is `&amp;`

Running it with the encoded ampersand will not throw an exception:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('system.xml.linq')
[system.xml.linq.xdocument]::parse('<node>&amp;</node>')
```